# Magento 2 magento theme:uninstall

Tags: magento2

I've installed a theme in Magento 2.0.5 EE with composer with:

```
composer require snowdog/theme-blank-sass
```

Later i removed it with

```
composer remove snowdog/theme-blank-sass
```

but in the backend Stores->Configuration->General->Design it is still present.
So googling i've found the official guide to theme uninstall:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-theme-uninstall.html#instgde-install-uninst-theme-over

I installed the theme again with composer and then tried:

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento theme:uninstall frontend/Snowdog/blank
```

but after 20 minutes the output is

```
Enabling maintenance mode
Removing frontend/Snowdog/blank from database
Removing frontend/Snowdog/blank from Magento codebase
```

With xdebug i've found that the problem is at /vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/ThemeUninstaller.php at line 71 that actually try to remove theme files with composer.

how can i remove it manually?

Comment: running `bin/magento setup:uninstall` and installing magento again didnt help